# How can i use cach network image in my flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I am trying to install cached network image  package in my flutter project but i keep getting this error message

> Resolving dependencies... Because cached_network_image >=3.2.0 depends
> on flutter_cache_manager ^3.3.0 which depends on http ^0.13.0,
> cached_network_image >=3.2.0 requires http ^0.13.0. So, because
> project depends on both cached_network_image ^3.2.3 and http ^1.0.0,
> version solving failed. exit code 1
>
> Resolving dependencies... Because cached_network_image >=3.2.0 depends
> on flutter_cache_manager ^3.3.0 which depends on http ^0.13.0,
> cached_network_image >=3.2.0 requires http ^0.13.0. So, because
> depends on both cached_network_image ^3.2.3 and http ^1.0.0, version
> solving failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a dependency conflict in your project. Temporarily, you can downgrade your `http` package to a version that is compatible with both `cached_network_image` and your project (e.g., `http: ^0.13.6`).

Also there is a [pull request](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter_cached_network_image/pull/845) in the `cached_network_image` repository that solves this problem, but it hasn't been merged yet.

Answer (score 0):

There is dependency conflict in your project. And I think you can resolve via using `dependency_overrides:` in you `pubspec.yaml`.

`dependency_overrides:` is for manual override. you are
I think manually overriding the `http:` and `cached_network_image:` packages to a specific version would solve this problem.

Like this.

```
dependency_overrides:
  http: 0.1x.x
  cached_network_image: 3.x.x
```

For the version of each package, Please choice the appropriate version by referring to your Flutter SDK and Dart SDK versions.